# Adding Jquery Confirm For Deleting Record

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery/ajax and php/mysql For CRUD opartions i've delete link were i click on a link it deletes my record i want jquery confirm before deleting record!!

can somebody help in putting confirm code in my jquery code!!

Thanks!!

**Jquery Code**

```
$('#demo').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var edittrid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    data = "deleteid=" + edittrid + "&actionfunction=deleteData";
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != 'error') {
                $('#demo').html(response);
                createInput();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$('#demo').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    if (confirm('do you wanna delete?')) {
        // user pressed yes
    }
});
```